# Multiprocess.Process not exiting on empty Queue

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a large number of objects to iterate over, and I thought that multiprocessing would speed up the work considerably.  However, this simple example seems to hang once I increase the core count.

It hangs on the `p.join()` line, and if I terminate and check, `q_in.empty()` returns `True` and the output queue has the appropriate number of items.

What's causing it to hang?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def worker_func(q_in, q_out, w):
    time.sleep(1)
    while not q_in.empty():
        # Simple code standing in for more complex operation
         q_out.put(str(w) + '_' + str(q_in.get()))

def setup_func(x):
    q_in = Queue()
    for w in range(x):
        q_in.put(w)

    q_out = Queue()
    return((q_in, q_out))

def test_func(num_cores, q_in, q_out):
    processes = []

    for w in range(num_cores):
        p = Process(target=worker_func, args=(q_in, q_out, w))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    output_ls = []
    while not q_out.empty():
        output_ls.append(q_out.get())

    return(output_ls)

q_in, q_out = setup_func(1000)
test_func(1, q_in, q_out) # This returns without issue for num_cores = 1 or 2

q_in, q_out = setup_func(1000)
test_func(5, q_in, q_out) # This hangs for num_cores = 5
```

Comment: Doubt it's system related.  I tried on two systems, both of which have at least 8 cores each

Comment: From the docs on `multiprocessing.Queue.empty` _Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable._. Personally, I put a `None` for each process at the end of the queue and have processes exit when they see it. That way I can just wait on the get without polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple processes pulling from the queue. The queue may have data but by the time you get around to fetching it, another process has consumed it. [multiprocessing.Queue.empty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty) says *Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable.*

An alternate approach is to put a process end sentinels at the end of the queue, one per process. When the process sees the sentinel, it exits. In your case, `None` is a good option.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def worker_func(q_in, q_out, w):
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        msg = q_in.get()
        if msg is None:
            break
        q_out.put(str(w) + '_' + str(msg))

def setup_func(x):
    q_in = Queue()
    for w in range(x):
        q_in.put(w)

    q_out = Queue()
    return((q_in, q_out))

def test_func(num_cores, q_in, q_out):
    processes = []

    for w in range(num_cores):
        q_in.put(None)
        p = Process(target=worker_func, args=(q_in, q_out, w))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    output_ls = []
    while not q_out.empty():
        output_ls.append(q_out.get())

    return(output_ls)

q_in, q_out = setup_func(1000)
test_func(1, q_in, q_out) # This returns without issue for num_cores = 1 or 2

q_in, q_out = setup_func(1000)
test_func(5, q_in, q_out) # This hangs for num_cores = 5
```

Comment: This is exactly the issue.  However, even after addressing this issue, there are other issues with using Queue to return worker output.  If run with `setup_func(10000)`, it will hang even for `num_cores = 1`.  I assume there size limits for the queue

Comment: That is strange. I set queue maxsize to a million, used 1 process and it hung at 5000 entries. I hate to toss out the word "bug" too casually, but, yeah, I suspect this is a bug. I'm a bit busy at the moment, but it would be interesting to dig into the source. Maybe there's something at bugs.python.org.

Comment: I added `print("exit")` at the end of the process worker. It printed but according to `ps ax|grep python`, the process didn't exit. Something in the worker wrapper that cleans up its own queues may have hung.

Comment: BTW - I'm on ubuntu. Your code shouldn't work on windows without the `if __name__ == "__main__"` trick so I assume you are apple or linux.

Comment: Yes, the code was run on a Mac.  The second testing machine was windows, and there I added in the standard `__name__` line.  Glad to hear that it's likely a bug, was confused how a commonly used class would fail at thousands of elements.